# SSIS OLE DB Command not recognizing parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, ssis, bids

I have an SSIS package I'm attempting to setup to do updates to records in my destination DB.  Unfortunately I don't have a staging table to work with at the moment so I can't just put everything there and then act on it.  I'm attempting to put the following statement into an OLE DB Command item:

```
Update [RTI.Datawall].dbo.Scores
set Value = ?, ValueAsText = ?, DateScored = ?
from [RTI.Datawall].dbo.Scores as sc
join [RTI.Datawall].dbo.StudentGrades as sg on sg.StudentGradeID = sc.StudentGradeID
join [RTI.Datawall].dbo.Assessments as a on a.AssessmentID = sc.AssessmentID
join [RTI.Datawall].dbo.Locations as l on l.LocationID = sg.LocationID
join [RTI.Datawall].dbo.Grades as g on g.GradeID = sg.GradeID
where sg.Active = 1
and sg.StudentID = ?
and sg.[Year] = ?
and sc.ScoreID = ?
and a.AssessmentID = ?
```

For all of my parameters in the Where clause I'm getting the same message:

> The multi-part identifier "(whatever identifier I have)" could not be bound."

In the future we're going to be able to fix this by importing a single key value from our source DB but that's a ways off.  Is there some reason SSIS won't parse the parameters?

Comment: There are a number of things that could be throwing this one off. Any way that you can post the parameter declarations as that would be a big piece of the puzzle

Comment: Hmm....  I haven't been explicitly declaring any parameters though?  SSIS has been picking them up automatically in the mappings.  Is there a spot where you set them?  Like, should I be crawling into the code to set them up?

Comment: you still need to declare what variable or value that will be associated with the index of the parameter array. More specifically I was concerned about the first three that you have there. It looks to me that you are assigning a column name via a parameter.

Comment: You didn't go into the parameters tab of the Command item and map the parameters to columns in your dataflow?   You need to do that.   Also, try changing the first line of your query to "Update sc".    (because you have aliased the table as "sc" in your FROM clause).

Comment: Apologies for being confused but SSIS has been picking up the paramaters automatically using the same block to do similar, but simpler, (Only one table is involved.), update scripts in several other places in the package.  Where in BIDS do you declare those parameters because I've actually been looking for something like that.  

In fact SSIS is picking up the first three parameters, the ones from the "set" clause no problem.  It's the ones in my "where" clause that are causing the error.  Apologies for the confusion and error on my part and thanks for the help man! :)

Comment: Where in BIDS?   Like I said, there should be a "Parameters" tab in properties box of your Ole DB Command item.   If there isn't one, please post a screenshot, so we have some idea what you're looking at.

Comment: Fetching a screenshot now but there's no paramaters tab per se.  There is a Column Mappings tab where I'd set which source column goes with which parameter.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/a/apps4pps.net/file/d/0B5xEvymVsE34eHlNaFRKUnplQ1E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The image you posted is not visible to the public